# What could help give the 'wobbly' status in Pokemon Rumble world?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

I'm pretty good at Pokémon Rumble games and in the most recent, (Pokémon Rumble World) I have been struggling to catch boss pokemon. I would like to know an easy strategy for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any attack that deals damage has a chance of inflicting *Wobble* status. An enemy Pokemon that gets KO'd while wobbling will always be caught. You can inflict this on bosses too, but only when they close their eyes and "charge up" between two attack phases.

A boss usually has a cyclic attack pattern: 3 primary attacks and 1 secondary attack. At the end of this pattern you should see white smoke coming out from their head. This is the interval you have to hit the boss.

*Wobbling* is essentially what happens when you critical an enemy. They get a typical anime "daze" effect. Stars pop out of their head and there's a swirl.

There are a few strategies to inflict the *Wobble* status:

- Increase the chances of making the enemy wobble, like using Pokemon with the trait **Gutsy** (better + or ++ version) and by maxing out your *Wobble tree* whenever you can.
- A high wobbling chance move like **Frost Breath**, **Storm Throw** and **Spacial Rend**.
- Teach **Focus Energy** which increases the critical hit ratio, and therefore the wobbling chance too.
- Attacks that have a high hit ratio but low damage. **Fling** and **Endeavor** are good examples. Once wobbling, use a super-effective secondary move to quickly defeat the boss.

I suggest you to use a **Gutsy** Pokemon with a weak move like **Endeavor** (which slowly reduces enemy's health and then, when his health is lower than yours, it deals always 1 damage) or **Leech Seed** (reduces 4-5 HP for few seconds). This grants you a lot of chances for wobble.

Anyway, sometimes you can capture a boss Pokemon without them wobbling at all. If they "sparkle", that's a guaranteed capture regardless of how you KO them.

<sub>NOTE: Combo should also influence how likely you are to capture a Pokemon, but I have no evidence of this.</sub>

Source: [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/141816-pokemon-rumble-world/71594012)

Comment: Ok I've heard a similar strategy. I guess I should start trying it.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit OT, but is the "sparkle"ness a random occurence?

Comment: @gitsitgo Yes, I'm pretty sure of it. There's no logic behind it, it can happen randomly to a boss or a wondering enemy.

Answer (score 3):

Critically Hitting a Pokémon causes it to become 'wobbly' for a short amount of time. Defeating it within this window of 'wobbly-ness' provides a 100% capture rate.

Hope this helped!~

Answer (score 2):

I find if you use lots of moves before the boss does its first attack(basically at the very beginning) and defeat it before it starts missing, it sometimes let's you have it,I got 4 bosses in a row with that strategy.

Answer (score -1):

if the pokemon is shiny than that helps you catch it also to get a wobbly pokemon you should keep hitting them with super efective moves until it is on pretty low health wait until it smokes and when its tierd hit with a super effective move and you should catch it or if it doesen't die it might woble you might need a crit though hope this helps it works for me